# Need to calculate overages using Stripe

Tags: stripe-payments

I am building a messaging app that uses Stripe. At the end of each month, I need to check if the user has sent over their allotted amount of texts. I have set up my webhook to call my endpoint on `invoice.created`. Then I need to get the 'start date' and 'end date' to create a query. I am trying to use `invoice.getPeriodStart()` and `invoice.getPeriodEnd` but they seem to be the exact same time (`1496677660`).

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce your error - for all of my `invoice.created` events, the `period_start` and `period_end` are different.  Which language/Stripe library (and which version) are you using?

Comment: I am using stripe-java version 4.7.0

Comment: @alexrbrown those are identical on the first invoice since that invoice is charged immediately on subscription creation. You should simply ignore that first invoice in your code/logic.

Comment: You can refer to this guide for more information about Stripe Webhooks: https://stripe.com/docs/webhooks